# IntelliJ Idea JPA entities in src/test/

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, entity

I have an entity in src/test/java written just for tests. It seems that IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize it. When I'm attempting to write a query Intellij doesn't recognize the class as an entity, I can't write "select * from " - it marks the class as nonexistent.

I have tried mapping the class directly in persistence.xml with  but that doesn't work as well (IntlliJ still doesn't recognize it and in persistence.xml I have to mark it as plain text or IntelliJ will mark it as error as well).

Also, in all the entities that I have in src/main I can see the symbol that it is mapped:

[image]

However the one in src/test is not:

[image]

EDIT:

I am using JPA facet, not Hibernate (which requires `hibernate.cfg.xml` and not `persistence.xml`), and it allows only one `persistence.xml` file to be added

[image]

[image]

Comment: Choose `orm.xml` and in **JPA Mapping Descriptor** field set path to `persistence-test.xml`.

Comment: Still does not recognize the class. Is there something else beside directly mapping the entity in the persistence unit with `<class>` element?

Comment: Create [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and put your persistence xml files. Then give me link on it.

Comment: This [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGl4u44WRiI) will useful for you

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c9feffab53f5170a12cd

Comment: GitHub message: *Whoops. We seem to have missed the gist of that gist you were looking for.* You create a public Gist ?

Comment: Weird, edited the message - works on my end.

Comment: I checked you gist and have no idea :((. Try to explore this [article](http://www.hostettler.net/blog/2012/03/19/testing-jpa-in-java-se/). Should resolve your issue. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for everything. Will post a solution when and if I figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and answering for posterity:

As @dozortsev-anton mentioned, we need another xml file in `src/test/resources` - but instead of another `persistence.xml` with different persistence units, we need an actual `orm.xml` to map the entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 version="2.0">

    <entity class="my.wonderful.class">
        <table name="TABLE_NAME" />
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

Note that just writing the `<entity>` node (without the `table` element inside) is sufficient for IntelliJ IDEA to recognize the class as an entity and start auto-completing queries where this class is used. However, the column names will not be recognized:

[image]

(upon hovering you'll get the "Cannot resolve column..." error). 
The `table` element will fix this - by mapping the entity to the table (the same table as you have in the `@Table` annotation) all errors will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

For recognize you need set [IDEA Facets](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/managing-facets.html) for `scr/test` folder. Go to `Project Structure ->  Facets` and in `Descriptions` set path to `persistence.xml`:

[image]

But you don't need create entity for test. You should make test cases for entities that stored in `src/main/java/...` folder.

#### Update:

[image]

Comment: This facet is already configured... I am making a test for classes and entities which reside in `src/main/java`, for one of the test I am using another entity created just for the tests, therefore just this entity resides in `src/test/java`. I need the `persistence.xml` located in `src/main/java` to recognized the entity.

Comment: Thus you need create `persistence-test.xml` file for one test entity and add it to Hibernate facets that already defined.

Comment: I would appreciate some more elaboration - currently I have one `persistence.xml` in `src/main` and all the persistence units are defined in it. How the introduction of `persistence-test.xml` will affect the persistence units? Should it define different/duplicate persistent units? I am missing something in the flow here. Thanks!

Comment: @apines `persistence-test.xml` should have different persistent units

Comment: IDEA doesn't let me define another JPA facet for `persistence.xml`, just orm.xml, and I need to `main/persitence.xml` (obviously). As I have mentioned, I am missing something from the general flow here, so I would be more than grateful if you could elaborate. Thank you!

Comment: Moreover - copying the entire `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` to `src/test`, renaming to `persistence-test.xml` and making it the only facet (this way I get all the persistence units I am already using in the test class path that should recognize my missing DAO) didn't work as well.